# framework header search paths in XCode 4

Tags: xcode, qt, xcode4

IIRC, adding a framework in XCode 3 automagically added the correct linker and preprocessor (header) search paths to the project/target.  The new way of doing this in XCode 4 seems to be adding the frameworks to "Link Binary with Libraries" under "Build Phases" in the project/target settings.

What about header search paths?  I've just tried adding several Qt frameworks to my project in XCode 4, and the headers are not found until I manually add the correct paths to header search paths.  The project in question was started as a unix executable.. is this the reason?  In another iOS project I haven't had to specify the search paths, only the frameworks.  Some difference in the project "type"?

Or maybe I'm doing things correctly and there's some problem with the Qt frameworks?

Tyler

Comment: I just came across this and it really seems like a bug.